# Android webview crashes resumes from another application

Tags: android, html

In my app loading HTML content in web-view. From a web-view page I’m clicking on home button switching over to another application. So my app will run in background mode current app come in foreground mode. After 3 to 5 minutes web-view activity is getting killed whenever going into my app its getting crashed. But whenever going from another activity app is not crashing only going from web-view app is crashing. Tried to run in a background service but no use. Please give me a valid solution for this mysterious task.

Below is my part of code in service:

class Myservice extends Service
      {

```
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        web.loadUrl("file://" + fileurl);
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                TimerMethod();
            }

        }, Long.valueOf(3000), Long.valueOf(3000));
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Called on service stopped
        super.onCreate();
        myTimer.cancel();
        }
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this works or not.

Try to add this to WebView

```
web.loadData("notreal/", "text/htm", "utf-8");
```